# java difference between system.out.println() and println()

Tags: java, println

I was wondering if there was a difference between these two 
e.g.

```
System.out.println("Hello World");
```

and

```
println("Hello World");
```

I know they print the same thing, but is there anything different? (I'm new to java, so I don't know so far)

In other words, does the "System.out" change anything?

Comment: I don't think the latter will compile.

Comment: If looking for print and prinln ,
println() will print an end-of-line character, while print() will not

Comment: Please show a complete small program example, complete with import statements, since without this information your question doesn't quite make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference, because they are not calling the same method.

Assuming the second statement actually compile, it means that the `println("Hello World")` call is for a method that is either:

- defined in your class
- inherited from a super class
- a default method inherited from an interface (Java 8+)
- statically imported<sup>1</sup>

Now, the local/inherited/imported `println(String s)` method *could* just have been implemented to call `System.out.println(s)`, which would make it *behave* the same as the direct call to `System.out.println(s)`, but that's different.

---

<sup>1) Since you cannot statically import `java.lang.System.out.println()` (it is not a static method), it would have to be statically imported from some other class.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

You might have a local method called `println` or a static import. So:

```
private void println(String str) {
    //
}
```

or

```
import static java.lang.System.out;
```

but then it'd have to be:

```
out.println("bla bla");
```

If you are using an IDE, try to open its declaration (<kbd>F3</kbd> in Eclipse)  and see where it takes you.

Comment: Sorry, i mean the function println()

Comment: @RandyHuang those are methods, java prefers to call them method.

Comment: If you static import `System.out`, you'd have to write `out.println()`, so that's obviously not what's going on. As for the local method, in order for `println("Hello World")` to work, the method would have to take a `String` parameter.

Comment: @Andreas 1)No, I won't. 2)Added a string as parameter.

Comment: `import static java.lang.System.out` only means that you can reference `out` without qualification. It does *not* add `println()` to the namespace. Compile error: *The method println(String) is undefined*